# Swift - How to use pushViewController in NSObject

Tags: swift

I have a slide in/out side menu which is called when leftBarButtonItem in nab bar is tapped.

And I coded the slide menu with NSObject and I know NSObject doesn't have the pushViewController method.

```
navigationController?.pushViewController
```

I have a menu in UITableView in the NSObject and I want push viewController.

How can I make this work? Thank you.

```
import UIKit

class SlideMenuLauncher: NSObject, UITableViewDelegate, 
UITableViewDataSource {

...

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        let destinationVC: UIViewController
        switch indexPath.row {
        case 0:
            destinationVC = ControllerA()
        case 1:
            destinationVC = ControllerB()
        default:
            destinationVC = HomeController()
        }
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(destinationVC, animated: false)
    }

...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## 1.

You can make a `@property` of your `parentVC` in `SlideMenuLauncher` class.

```
var parentVC: UIViewController?
```

and then you can use this instead of `self`.

```
parentVC!.navigationController?.pushViewController(destinationVC, animated: false)
```

## 2.

You can post a notification instead of pushing from `SlideMenuLauncher` class and pass the `destinationVC` as object in notification. Observe this notification in your `parentVC` then fetch the `destinationVC` from notification object and push the controller.

## 3.

You can make a block or delegate of `didSelectRowAt` event.

**Block Example:**

```
/// Declare a block in `SideMenuLauncher`
typealias TableEventBlock = (_ controller: UIViewController) -> Void
var tableEventBlock: TableEventBlock?

/// In table did select method
if tableEventBlock != nil {
    tableEventBlock!(destinationVC)
}
```

You need to define its call back in `parentVC` (You can define it anywhere, Do it in `viewDidLoad:`) and will have to use `SideMenuLAuncher`'s instance.

```
sideMenuLauncherInstance.tableEventBlock = { controller in
     self.navigationController?.pushViewController(controller, animated: false)
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I chose "var parentVC: UIViewController?".